# Get-ScheduledTask command does not work in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find a scheduled task with having certain pattern in it's name, in my case the scheduled task should have this pattern "ServiceNow" in its name. For this I am using `Get-ScheduledTask` command, but this command fails in Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
$taskPattern = "ServiceNow"
$taskDetails = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -match $taskPattern  }
$taskName = $taskDetails.TaskName
```

This script fails with error :

> "Get-ScheduledTask : The term 'Get-ScheduledTask' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again."

Then I tried this approach which gives me the "(taskname Date&Time State)" but I don't know how to only extract the taskname from it's output.

```
$taskPattern = "ServiceNow" 
$taskExists = schtasks /query | select-string -patt $taskPattern 
$taskExists
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make it work in Windows Server 2008 R2 by only extracting the actual taskname? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 does support PS Version 5. Please try to upgrade the powershell, maybe that allows you to run `Get-ScheduledTask`. You can check your currently installed version with `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: I do not want to upgrade the Powershell Version. Isn't there a way to filter just the taskname?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't get `Get-ScheduledTask` at windows 2008 R2 as it was introduced for Windows 2012 and nobody backported it.  For more see the link at [github](https://github.com/PowerShell/ComputerManagementDsc/issues/108).

The comment that describes the situation the best is:

> Hi @dronkoff - This module is supported on PS 4.0. However, the
>   problem isn't in the version of PowerShell. The issue is that the
>   ScheduledTasks module, which this resource depends on, is not built
>   into Windows Server 2008R2. It was first included in Windows Server
>   2012.
>
> This is the case with many of the PowerShell modules: They are missing
>   from older versions of Windows (Networking for example). In the odd
>   occasion there is an easy work around. However in this case converting
>   the resource over to use schtasks.exe is not possible without a
>   complete rewrite and would probably result in something really
>   unstable and buggy (not to mention the problems that would arise with
>   different localized versions of schtasks). I really can't see this
>   happening unfortunately (unless someone else from the community has
>   some ideas on how to do this).
>
> But you are correct, this should be mentioned that Windows Server
>   2008R2 is not currently supported.

### The workaround

The way around it, is to use `schtask` with correct switches.

If you have it in the `Microsoft` folder as I have it in the example you just need to run:

```
schtasks /tn \Microsoft\ServiceNow /query /fo LIST
```

The output:

```
Folder: \Microsoft
HostName:      XXXXXACL06
TaskName:      \Microsoft\ServiceNow
Next Run Time: 7/4/2018 8:16:22 AM
Status:        Ready
Logon Mode:    Interactive only
```

If you want more details you can use the `/v` (verbose) switch:

```
schtasks /tn \Microsoft\ServiceNow /query /v > service_now_details.txt
```

**Edit** - to find a pattern

If you have only pattern to search you have to use some additional tool to search the string.  The windows natively supports `findstr` (or `Select-String` (short `sls`) in powershell):

To find the task name you can use then:

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST | findstr "ServiceNow"
```

OR even with wild charter

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST | findstr "ServiceNo*"
```

OR the `powershell` way:

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST | sls 'ServiceNo*'
```

The output in all cases will be something like this (since my task is named exactly `ServiceNow`):

`TaskName:      \Microsoft\ServiceNow`

**Edit2** case sensitivity

If you are searching for case insensitive string then:
for `findstr` you have to add `/I` to make it insensitive.  The powershell's `select-string` (sls) is naturally insensitive.

Comment: The task name is not exactly ServiceNow. It's name conatins this pattern "ServiceNow". I want to find out full name of this task

Comment: @beginner I see.  I'll edit the answer and add this option.

Comment: @beginner please don't forget to accept the answer when it answers your questions (upvote is nice to :) ) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How to make this query for case-insensitive cases? Suppose the task name is "servicenow" and not "ServiceNow", then how can we check for any insensitive cases? It is giving error because of case-sensitivity

Comment: @beginner the `powershell` version is case insensitive (you actually have to add a switch to make it case sensitive).  As for `findstr` you have to add `/I` to make it case-insenstivie (check `findstr /?` for all switches).

Answer (score 2):

There's a great script on GitHub, [Get-ScheduledTasks](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-ScheduledTasks.ps1) (note the S on the end of the service name).  This works on older versions of Windows going back to Windows Server 2003 / Windows XP.

Thanks to the amazing [Warren F](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/) (aka Rambling Cookie Monster) for creating & sharing this.