# ScheduledTask command does not work - is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a bat file to modify a scheduled task setting, for this I have tried these two methods (A-B):

**.BAT**

```
powershell -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Temp\config\tasks.ps1
```

A) tasks.ps1

```
$settingsSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$settingsSet.ExecutionTimeLimit = 'PT0S'
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName TaskStart -Settings $settingsSet
```

B) tasks.ps1

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask "TaskStart"
$task.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT0S"
Set-ScheduledTask $task
```

both work in w10, but in w7 I have the same error:

> The term '***' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

How can you make this in w7?
I would like to know how to modify the ExecutionTimeLimit.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell 4 Get-ScheduledTask and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658249/powershell-4-get-scheduledtask-and-windows)

Comment: not exactly, it's not clear

Comment: Basically, what it's saying is that `Get-ScheduledTask` won't ever work on Windows 7 because the cmdlet relies on some underlying OS component that is not present on that version of the OS.  You will need to use an alternative, such as `schtasks.exe`.  There is a little more detail in this other question: [Get-ScheduledTask command does not work in Windows Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147611/get-scheduledtask-command-does-not-work-in-windows-server-2008-r2/51147933)

Comment: I would like to know how to modify the ExecutionTimeLimit, not how to use the Get-ScheduledTask